# How can I make my csv file readable after uploading it in JupyterLite?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, linear-regression

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.read_csv('car_purchasing.csv')
df.head()
```

I keep getting this error whenever I run my code

```
EmptyDataError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [2], line 3
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 import numpy as np
----> 3 df=pd.read_csv('car_purchasing.csv', delim_whitespace=True)
      4 df.head()

File /lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py:311, in deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    305 if len(args) > num_allow_args:
    306     warnings.warn(
    307         msg.format(arguments=arguments),
    308         FutureWarning,
    309         stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310     )
--> 311 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File /lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py:680, in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, encoding_errors, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, on_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options)
    665 kwds_defaults = _refine_defaults_read(
    666     dialect,
    667     delimiter,
   (...)
    676     defaults={"delimiter": ","},
    677 )
    678 kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
--> 680 return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

File /lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py:575, in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    572 _validate_names(kwds.get("names", None))
    574 # Create the parser.
--> 575 parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    577 if chunksize or iterator:
    578     return parser

File /lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py:933, in TextFileReader.__init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    930     self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    932 self.handles: IOHandles | None = None
--> 933 self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)

File /lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py:1235, in TextFileReader._make_engine(self, f, engine)
   1232     raise ValueError(msg)
   1234 try:
-> 1235     return mapping[engine](f, **self.options)
   1236 except Exception:
   1237     if self.handles is not None:

File /lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/c_parser_wrapper.py:75, in CParserWrapper.__init__(self, src, **kwds)
     72     kwds.pop(key, None)
     74 kwds["dtype"] = ensure_dtype_objs(kwds.get("dtype", None))
---> 75 self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
     77 self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
     79 # error: Cannot determine type of 'names'

File /lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx:551, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
​
```

My csv file is readable on excel and I can see the data as shown in the [excel image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPAVF.png) but when I upload it in JupyterLite the data disappears as shown in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkQ4f.png)

I tried using the delimiter variation:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.read_csv('car_purchasing.csv', delim_whitespace=True)
df.head()
```

But it's not working. I still get the same error
How can I solve this?

This is the content in my csv file: [download the file](https://nam04.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.kaggle.com%2Fdatasets%2Fyashpaloswal%2Fann-car-sales-price-prediction&data=05%7C01%7CChitraDubey%40my.unt.edu%7Cc7defeb8eaa64fdf6a2008dabb843b51%7C70de199207c6480fa318a1afcba03983%7C0%7C0%7C638028473843126915%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C3000%7C%7C%7C&sdata=omIdVQ7bfFomLLQkCgjtRULqSCgFM1otzxIFkt3pIYI%3D&reserved=0)

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Perhaps we can help you further

Comment: I just editted it please check again

Comment: Could you provide the actual contents of the `.csv` file in text format? Not all, but just the first few rows ad columns

Comment: Ok. Let me do that

Comment: I have added a link for the file instead. I thought It'd be more helpful

Comment: try using `file= open('car_purchasing.csv', 'w') file.close()
pd.read_csv('car_purchasing.csv')`

Comment: Sorry, i am unable to reproduce the error. There seems to be an issue with the byte encoding, which may cause the error. Open the file in a text editor and save the file. Then reimport it again using `df=pd.read_csv('car_purchasing.csv', delimiter=',')`

Comment: I have tried both suggestions. But I still get an error

Comment: Try `pd.read_csv('car_purchasing.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1')` - that worked for me. You can detect file encodings with [`chardet`](https://pypi.org/project/chardet/).

Comment: @Timus It's still not working, same error code

Comment: One of the problems here is you aren't addresing the root cause, it seems. I may be wrong but if the viewer in JupyterLite in [your image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkQ4f.png) isn't seeing anything there (that's the CSV_table view), then opening it with `pd.read_csv`() isn't going to probably work ever. In the comments you say you tried the re-importing suggestion but don't update your post/comments to reflect this? Does the JupyterLite viewer open that `.csv` file. What if you right-click on the CSV file in the file navigator in JupyterLite and select `Open with Editor`? Update with that.

Comment: Could it simply be you are trying something too large for 'uploading' into JupyterLite on your machine? The in-browser WASM has limited abilities. (I didn't download your data and couldn't tell from the Kaggle page actually how big it was and so I may be way off base here with this avenue of investigation.) Have you tried making a new Excel file with a tiny fraction of your data, like just the top ten rows and place that into JupyterLite and open it with the CSV_table viewer or the Editor directly?